# How to run R code with the Parallel package on a cluster consisting of a local machine as master and several remote VPS machines as workers?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, vps

I am trying to run parallel R code, with the parallel package, in a cluster formed by my local machine as master and a remote VPS as worker. In the VPS I have RStudio installed. I have the Rstudio link, the username and the password of the VPS. Likewise, from the VPS I have the IP, user and password to enter Ubuntu.
I have done tests with parallel code on my local machine and it works without problems. However, I don't know how to form the cluster where my local machine is the master and the VPS is the worker. Therefore I don't know how to communicate my local machine with the VPS.

I found these instructions:
workers <- c ("n1.remote.org", "n2.remote.org", "n3.remote.org")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK (workers, dryrun = TRUE)

But I don't know what should I put in workers <- c ("n1.remote.org", "n2.remote.org", "n1.remote.org"). Specifically, what do I have to put in n1, in n2 and n3? The thing is, I don't know how to establish communication between my local machine and the VPS. Where do I have to indicate that my machine is local and where that the VPS is the remote one ?.

Likewise, I do the following test on my local machine:

```
library ("parallel")
find_workers <- function (nodes) {
  nodes <- unique (nodes)
  cl <- makeCluster (nodes)
  on.exit (stopCluster (cl))

  ns <- clusterCall (cl, fun = detectCores)
  rep (nodes, times = ns)
}

workers <- find_workers (c ("n1", "n2", "n3"))
cl <- makeCluster (workers)
```

But my machine I think it goes in infinite loop and does not produce any output.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me, and put an example of how to do that.

Greetings.
Luciano Maldonado

Comment: You basically need to figure out how to SSH into those machines first.  I think the Section 'Failing to set up remote workers' of `?parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK` (https://parallelly.futureverse.org/reference/makeClusterPSOCK.html#failing-to-set-up-remote-workers) could be a good start.

Comment: yes, I downloaded and installed puTTy on my local machine. I configure puTTY with the IP of the VPS and select SSH. In this way I can access the VPS with my user root and my password. But I don't know what else I can do to create the cluster on my local machine ?. what do I put in workers <- c ("n1.remote.org", "n2.remote.org", "n3.remote.org")? the IP of the VPS ?.

Comment: @HenrikB, Obviously, I have no knowledge of how to place the names or IPs of the machines that I am going to use in the cluster. It's just that, I'd like to see a simple example. And from there, I think I will have no problem using any of the Parallel, Future or Parallelly packages. Already on my local machine I can work, without problems, with a cluster formed by the cores of my processor.

Comment: "Obviously...".  Sorry, I know nothing about VPS - not even sure what it is and even less how it works.  Just like `parallel::makePSOCKcluster()`, `parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK()` needs either the hostnames or the IP numbers of the "machines" where the R workers should run.  For example, I can ssh to my other laptop on my local network via it's IP number, so I can use, for instance, `workers <- c("localhost", "192.168.1.42")` to run one worker on my local machine and one on that other laptop. Maybe VPS is a completely different beast(?)

Comment: BTW, do you have Windows 10 on your local machine?  If so, then you can use the built-in `ssh` client just like on Unix and macOS.  That'll make your life much easier than using PuTTY and it's rather odd `plink` SSH client.  For example, you'll be able to easily set up SSH keys, which is required in order to launching remote R workers automatically.  Having to enter a password manually each time is extremely cumbersome and not recommended.

Comment: Very good, very grateful. Henrik, with the information you told me to read and everything else you have indicated and commented on, I am now clearer. I'm going to see how I progress. Sure, I'll ask you more questions later.
Yes, I have windows 10. On the other hand, a VPS (Virtual Private Server) is a partition for your use, within a physical server, in which you can install an operating system and in which you can work as if it were an exclusive machine of yours.